# How to search a string with a single character?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am creating a guess the Synonym game base off of what name the user enter in at the beginning. For now I have hard coded the values,`$word, $str, $clue`

I display the words in a table, each row has two strings. One being the clue giving you a hint on what the synonym is and then the synonym its self.

So, I for the life of cant / dont know how to compare a single character to a string of characters. I've tried `strpos(), strstr()` but compares the string letter for letter: 'Con'rad - 'Con'cept.

What I'm looking for is something along the line of what I have below:

- Conrad compare the letter C to all the characters in the word Concept
- Conrad compare the letter O to all the character in the word Support
- Conrad compare the letter N to all the characters in the word Design
- Conrad compare the letter R to all the character in the word Fresh
- Conrad compare the letter A to all the characters in the word Aged
- Conrad compare the letter D to all the character in the word Glad

Here Is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Me</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<style>
    table{
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    th{
        background-color:#CAD704;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;}
    td{
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-left: 5px;
        }

    tr:nth-child(even) {background: #ECF0CB}
    tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #F6F8E7}

    .floating-box {
        float: left;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 5px;

    }

    input[type="text"] {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
    }
    input.char[type="text"] {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background-color : #d1d1d1;
    } 
    .button {
        background-color: #76AEEB; /* Green */
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 15px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 150px;
    }       

    .sub {border-radius: 12px;}     
</style>
<?php 

$word ="Conrad";

$str = array("Concept", "Support", "Design", "Fresh", "Aged","Glad");
$clue = array("Idea", "Keep", "Make","New", "Old", "Happy");

echo $test = implode(" ", $str) , " <b>Implode</b> <br />";
echo $cluestr = implode(" ", $clue) , " <b>Implode</b> <br />";

$strlen = strlen($test);
$strlen2 = strlen($cluestr);

echo $count = count($str). " elements in array <br />";
echo $count2 = count($clue). " elements in array <br />";

echo $strlen , " string length<br />";
echo $strlen2 , " string length<br />";

echo $test , " String <br />";
echo $cluestr , " String <br /><br />";


?>  


 <div id="content">
 <table>
 <tr>
     <th>Clue</th><th colspan="100">Synonym</th>
    </tr> 
     <tr>
         <!-- This is the start -->
 <?php  
  $p = 0;       
  $h = 0;
    for( $i = 0; $i <= $strlen; $i++ ) {

            if ($p == 0){
                echo "<td> $clue[$h]</td>";
                $h++;
            }
        $charW = substr( $word, $i, 1 );    
        $char = substr( $test, $i, 1 );

        if($char == " " || $char ==""){ 
        echo"
            <td style='visibility: hidden;'>
                <div class='floating-box'>
                    <input type='text' maxlength='1'>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style='visibility: hidden;'>
                <div class='floating-box'>
                    <input type='text' maxlength='1'>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>";
          $p=0;
         continue; 
        }else {
            echo "<td>
                    <div class='floating-box'>
                        <input type='text' value='$char' maxlength='1' class='char'>
                    </div>
                </td>";
        }
        $p++;
    }


       ?>            
         <!-- The end -->

     </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
```

If something doesn't make sense please let me know and I'll try and clarify it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a simple implementation:

```
$string = "conrad";
$array = ['Concept', 'Support', 'Design', 'Fresh', 'Aged', 'Glad'];

for ($i = 0, $n = strlen($string); $i < $n; $i++) {
    if (strstr(strtolower($array[$i]), strtolower($string[$i]))) {
        echo $string[$i] . " belongs to " . $array[$i] . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "fail\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
c belongs to Concept
o belongs to Support
n belongs to Design
r belongs to Fresh
a belongs to Aged
d belongs to Glad
```

live sample: https://3v4l.org/k9A5K

Comment: Thanks for the help and the site that you posted a working example on is pretty cool and useful so thanks for both.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative:

```
$word  = 'conrad';
$array = ['Concept', 'Support', 'Design', 'Fresh', 'Aged', 'Glad'];

foreach(str_split($word) as $position => $letter) {
    if(stripos($array[$position], $letter) !== false) {
        echo "$letter found in $array[$position]<br>\n";
    }
}
```

- Split the word into letters and loop them, exposing the position
- Check for the letter in the word at the same position case-insensitive

Comment: Thanks for the help and explaining what is going on in your code! There is no way anytime soon i would have figured it out the way you did.